# MongoDB Connection in Rstudio with odbc

Tags: r, mongodb, odbc

I'm trying to connect to a mongoDB database using library(odbc) in R. First I installed the driver from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-odbc-driver/releases/) and then I have used the following method:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
  Driver        = "MongoDB ODBC 1.3.0 Unicode Driver",
  Server        = "xxxxx",
  AuthMechanism = "SCRAM-SHA-1", 


  Port          = 27017,
  Database      = "test",
  UID           = "utest",
  PWD           = "ptest"
)
```

However the following error will happen:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:983: 08S01: [MySQL][ODBC 1.3(w) Driver]Lost
>   connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication
>   packet', system error: 10060

I would appreciate any help.Thanks

Comment: Facing the same issue. Any updates on how it got resolved,